# Not seeing decision boundary of SVM plot in R

Tags: r, plot, svm

I am new using SVM in r. I am doing analysis on a breast cancer dataset and I would like to plot the decision boundary on two of the features. but the boundary does not show where it supposed to show. The following is the code:

```
set.seed(134)
fitc = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10, search = "random", savePredictions = T)
modfitsvm = train(diagnosis~., data = trainset, method = "svmLinear", trControl = fitc, tuneLength = 10)

plot(modfitsvm)

bestmod = svm(diagnosis~., data = trainset, kernel = "linear", cost = 0.18)
# train data error
svm.ytrain<-trainset$diagnosis
svm.predy<-predict(bestmod, trainset)
mean(svm.ytrain!=svm.predy) 

# test data error 
svm.ytest<-testset$diagnosis
svm.predtesty<-predict(bestmod, testset)
mean(svm.ytest!=svm.predtesty) 


svmtab = confusionMatrix(svm.predtesty,testset$diagnosis)
fourfoldplot(svmtab$table, conf.level = 0, margin = 1, main=paste("SVM Testing(",round(svmtab$overall[1]*100,3),"%)",sep=""))
```

[image: This is the out put plot of the last line of code.]

I am not seeing boundary but the model achieved 94% accuracy.

Comment: `plot(bestmod, trainset, radius_mean~radius_se) ` This is the command that I used to produce this plot

Comment: It is difficult to tell without the dataset, but I tried with 'cats' dataset as a reference using your code (only changing the variables and output to train and test the SVM) and it totally worked. Perhaps the high-density of samples is overlapping the decision boundaries? Try with another dataset to test if your plot() function is working, it did for me.

Comment: I tried 'cats' too. It works fine. So I was wondering if it's the problem of my svm model, but the precision is 94%. So it shouldn't be something wrong with the model. I also want make it clear that the dataset has 30 features.